# ni tsuite 「について」 vs ni yoreba 「によれば」

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between ni tsuite and ni yoreba, because the meaning is seems the same, regarding and according to. If its different when or what situation I can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for both terms in the dictionary, you will find out that they are quite different:

> について means about, concerning.
>   によれば means according to.

Just like in English, these similar phrases are not interchangeable:

> 天気予報によれば今夜{こんや}は[雪]{ゆき}になるそうだ。
>   **According to** the weather report, there will be snow tonight.
>   天気予報について何も知りません。
>   I know nothing **about** the weather report.